# remake selecting values in select

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have to remake this select, it can be written like only one select without any subselects. i have no idea how to solve it.

```
select e.exam_name, e.percentage, cc.cert_name, c.company_name, cert_type_name, cert_level_name, version_number,cert_version_name, count(*) as pocet, 
        MIN(ppp.points) as minPoints,
        MAX(ppp.points) as maxPoints,
        (
            ((select count(*) from registration reg where pass = '1')*100)/
              (select count(*) from registration ppp)        
        ) as prctU,   

        (select count(*) from registration ppp where ppp.exam_id = e.exam_id and pass='0') as numFail    

        from person  p
        join registration ppp using (id_cert_person)
        join provide_exam pe using(id_cert_company)
        join company c using(id_cert_company)
        join exam e on (e.exam_id=pe.exam_id)
        join required_exam re on (re.exam_id=e.exam_id)
        join certificate cc using(cert_id)
        join cert_type cet using(id_cert_type)
        left join address addr on (c.id_address = addr.id_address)
        left join cert_level cl using(id_cert_level)
        left join version_db vd on(vd.id_version_db =cc.id_version_db )  
        group by exam_name,percentage, cert_name, company_name, cert_type_name, cert_level_name, version_number,cert_version_name;
```

Comment: have you tried anything? Could you show your attempt to try and remove all the so called sub-selects, and what didn't work?

Comment: actually i have no idea how to do it, i am just reading and googling , and i didnt find any solution :-/ it gives me error:
SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"  ....

Comment: Could you show your failed attempt? Then we can look into why it didn't work.

Comment: the select what i put here is my failed attempt...

Comment: I see, your question sounds like you want to remake the working select as pictured to exclude the sub-selects. Sorry I don't really understand what you want to achieve here.

Comment: Yes this is what i need , exlude sub-selects. There should be way how to write only one select without subselects , without changing its functionality.

Comment: I just need some idea, how to remake it without using sub-selects ,but do not corrupt functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written now, the subqueries would need to be repeated in the `group by`, as although they contain aggregate functions internally, they are not themselves aggregates in the main select list. Hence your error.

I'm not sure how selective the joins are but as a starting point you can do something like:

```
select e.exam_name, e.percentage, cc.cert_name, c.company_name, cert_type_name,
    cert_level_name, version_number,cert_version_name,
    count(*) as pocet, 
    MIN(ppp.points) as minPoints,
    MAX(ppp.points) as maxPoints,
    100 * count(case when pass = '1' then ppp.some_field end)
      / count(ppp.some_field) as prctU,
    count(case when pass = '0' then ppp.some_field) as numFail
from person  p
...
```

The `count()` function ignores nulls; the `case` inside means that only the relevant rows are counted.

This avoids querying the same tables again, particularly as the subqueries weren't correlated to the main query properly. But without knowing the schema and keys this may count the same values multiple times, so you may need to use a key field and potentially the distinct keyword within the count function calls. Obviously use a real columnna,e instead of `some_field`.

It looks odd to have a pass/fail flag as a character but set to '0' or '1'; if it's really a number field then those shouldn't be in quotes.